# How to show selected table row id in the address bar with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I have this below script that load the selected table row details in a div in the same page with ajax.

```
 $('.positiontitle-link').click(
  function(){
   var durl = $(this).attr('ref');
   $('#details').load(durl)   
 }
)
```

This is my Table where it have two column. First column used to list the jobs from MySQL database and the second used to view the selected row full details.

```
<table class="table1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%; z-index:1; top:0; position: absolute;">

  <tr>
    <td width="30%" style=" min-width:40px;padding:0; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); height: 100%; bottom: 0; top:0;" valign="top">
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-x:hidden; height: 100%; position: inherit; bottom: 0; top:0;">
    <?php
    require "module/call.php";
    ?>
</div>

</td>
<td width="60%" style="min-width:40px;padding:0; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); height: 100%; bottom: 0; top:0;" valign="top"><div id="details" style="overflow:auto; width:100%; border-left-width: thin; border-right-width: 0; border-top-width: thin; border-bottom-width: 0; height: 100%; bottom: 0; top:0;"></div></td>


    <td width="20%" style="padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***This is the imageof the table***
[image]

This is the ***call.php*** codes

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job  where approved='1' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

echo "<table id='maintable' class='table-fill' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th position='fixed' overflow='hidden' width='10%'>Job Title</th> 
<th position='fixed' width='5%'>Company Name</th>
<th width='5%'>Closing Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
        if (strlen($row['positiontitle']) > 20) $row['positiontitle'] = substr($row['positiontitle'], 0, 60) . "...";
      echo "<tr onclick='get_data(123)' ref='job.details.php?id=".$row['id']."' target='content' class='positiontitle-link'>";
      echo "<td data-id='<?php echo $row['id']?>'><font style='text-shadow: none;'>" . $row['positiontitle'] . "</font></a></td>";
      echo "<td data-id='<?php echo $row['id']?>'>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td data-id='<?php echo $row['id']?>'>" . $row['closingdate'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
     }

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and this is the ***details.php*** codes

```
<?php

   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

   $jobdetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo ''.$jobdetails['positiontitle'].'';?>
    </title>


</br>


<div style="width:100%; margin-top:-20px;">

<!-------------------------------------------Start of Right Sidebar----------------------------------------------------------------> 
    <div style="float:left; font-size: 14px; width:20%;"class="ara-form">
    <header style="padding-top: 25px; font-size: 14px; color:#666666; padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px;">
    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

   $jobdetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo '<strong>Job Title</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['positiontitle'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Company Name</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['companyname'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Location</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['location'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Closing Date</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['closingdate'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Number of Vacancy</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['numberofvacancy'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Job Category</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['jobcategory'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Duration</strong><hr class="style-six">'.$jobdetails['duration'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Employment Type</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['employmenttype'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Salary</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['salary'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Timing</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['timing'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Nationality</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['nationality'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong><hr class="style-six">'.$jobdetails['gender'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Experience</strong><hr class="style-six">'.$jobdetails['experience'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Education</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['education'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'</p></br>';
?>
</header>


</div>
<!---------------------------------------------End of Right Sidebar------------------------------------------->    

<div style="float:left; font-size: 14px; width:80%;" class="ara-form">
    <fieldset style="font-size: 14px; color:#666666;">




<!-------------------------------------------------Start Time viewed Button------------------------------------------------>    
    <div style="width:100px; float:right; padding-left:2px; padding-top: 10px;">

    <?php
    include "module/button/job.views.php";
    ?>

    </div>
<!---------------------------------------------------End Time viewed Button------------------------------------------------->     





<!-----------------------------------------------Start Main Content----------------------------------------------->      
    <?php
    echo '<p><strong>Company Background</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['background'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong>Job Summary</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['summary'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong>Job Duties and Responsibilities</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['duty'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong>Qualification</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['qualification'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong>Skills</strong><hr class="style-six"></br> '.$jobdetails['skill'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong>Submission Guideline</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['submission'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong>Words to search this job</strong><hr class="style-six"> '.$jobdetails['search'].'</p></br>';
    ?>
<!-------------------------------------------------End Main Content-----------------------------------------------> 


    </fieldset></div>
```

**My Question is**

1- I want to show the selected row id in the address bar

2- I want to show unclicked.php in the `details` div when no row selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to change the content of the address bar without refreshing the page, you'll either need to use the HTML5 History API or a hashbang URL.

   - HTML5 History API: This will allow you to change the content of the address bar to whatever you like, but the browser support is [limited](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history). An example is as follows:

     `history.pushState(null, "", "/test");`

     This will change the page URL to `yoursite.com/test`.
     You can use this to add a row-related extension to the URL, eg. yoursite.com/table/row/20.
     See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) for a more in-depth explanation of how the API works.
   - Hashbang URL: This is a less clean solution, but is somewhat simpler and will work on all browsers. Your URL will look like `yoursite.com/table#row20`. (If you already have a `#` in the page URL, this will not work). Just call `window.location = "#row20"` to add `#row20` to the current page URL.

If you are going to change the URL when a new row is selected, then you should also check the URL on page load and preselect a row if required. Eg. requesting `yoursite.com/table#row20` would return the page with row 20 already selected.

2. `$('#details').load('path/to/unclicked.php')`  will load the file's contents into the div. If you want this to occur on page load, just wrap it in a call to `$(document).ready()`. Simply make the AJAX request again if the user is able to deselect all rows.

Comment: Thanks i tried HTML5 history API, but it is not working.
this is how i embed it with the rest of the code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cpkLbthh/)

Comment: Is the script tag where the code is contained being repeated inside a `foreach` statement? If it is, try `console.log("<?php echo $row['id']?>")` and see what comes up in the console (easy on Chrome or Firefox).  If it isn't, it may be easier to set `data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"` on the HTML row itself and then use `$(this).data('id')` to retrieve it in the script.

Comment: I didn't get it how to use

Comment: Are there any errors appearing in the browser console when you load the page?

Comment: Instead of having the echo statement there, add a `data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"` attribute to the `td` tag of each row. You can then access this data in your script using `$(this).data('id')`.

Comment: when i add `data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"` in td then dreamweaver gives me error _There is a syntax error in line 27_ which the td line

Comment: Could you update your question to show the file and the error?

Comment: Ah, you're already in a PHP section, so you don't need the PHP tags. Looking at your code, the `data-id` only needs to be added to the `<tr>`. Remove it from the `<td>`'s and change the `<tr>` to `echo "<tr onclick=\"get_data(123)\" ref=\"job.details.php?id=".$row['id']."\" target=\"content\" class=\"positiontitle-link\" data-id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">";`

Comment: i add it and know what should i do

Comment: Now update your script to the contents of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8g7vgbf/1/

Comment: thanks it worked and changed the address bar url but when i use that url to reach this job from another tab then it say object not found.

Comment: Your site isn't configured to handle URLs like that (it tries to find the normal page), and that can't really be changed, so you might be better off using a hashbang URL as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g86zg0L5/1/.

Comment: Thanks but it is not viewing the job with that id instead it opens first job

Comment: That's as expected, the contents of this fiddle should solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/v01Lsrug/

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v01Lsrug/1/ It now has some debug messages, please replace the other script and then tell me what the console returns.

Comment: i replaced and nothings happen and the consule says ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Alright, here's a slightly different version: http://jsfiddle.net/g7e62e6u/2/ Please check the console for errors it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, but when i click back in browser nothings happen. just the url in address bar changes and the job doesn't load.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the script that you are currently using so that I can debug?

Comment: That code should theoretically work. I can't debug your environment for you. Use `console.log` and PHP `echo` to track the flow of data through your site. Make sure that the hash is being read correctly, the AJAX request works correctly, and your script is loading at the right time.

Comment: yes, but not loading the job that you viewed previously.

Comment: Have you tested the things mentioned in my above comment?

Comment: thanks i am newbie to console.log and i don't know how to use it

Comment: It's just `console.log('mystring')` or `console.log(myvar)`. Any JS object or literal can be placed in a `console.log`.

Comment: shall i use it in console of chrome, if so then chrome console said `undefined`

Comment: console.log('mystring') IN CHROME CONSOLE

Comment: Are you typing that into the console or running it in your script?

Comment: i am typing it in console

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can you please also fix the back button problem because when i click on back button the address bar url changes but the page doesn't load.

Comment: Please chech this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581288/previous-page-is-not-loading-when-browsers-back-button-pressed-in-ajax