# Previous page is not loading when browser's back button pressed in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that have two columns which use ajax.

In the first column i list the jobs with the help of *`job.call.php`* and when a job have been clicked in first column then the details of the job loads in the second column with the help of *`job.details.php`*.

This is the jquery code that perform the ajax loading process:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.hash) {
       var id = window.location.hash.replace('#id-', '');
       $('#details').load('job.details.php?id=' + id);

       //-----job.unclick.hide.row.select
      var div = document.getElementById("job.unclicked");
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
    });
```

This is the table:

```
        <td colspan="3" style="padding:0; width:20%; height:20%;">
            <?php include "job.header.php";?>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:400px; padding:0; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); vertical-align: initial;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-height:100%; height:100px; margin:0; padding:0;" valign="top">

              <tr>
                <td style="width:400px; padding:0; vertical-align: initial; height: 35px;">
                    <div style="position: fixed;z-index: 1;">
                    <table  border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:400px; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);'>
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th position='fixed' overflow='hidden' width='19%'>Job Title</th> 
                                <th position='fixed' width='7%'>Location</th>
                                <th width='5%'>Expires</th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td style="width:400px; padding:0; vertical-align: initial; height:100%; bottom: 0; top:0; ">
                <?php require "module/job.call.php";?>
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>

        </td>

        <td width="100%" style="min-width:600px; padding:0; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); height:100%; bottom: 0; top:0; border: 1px; border-style: groove;"  valign="top">
            <div class="content mCustomScrollbar">
            <div id="job.unclicked" style="width:100%; border-left-width: thin; border-right-width: 0; border-top-width: thin; border-bottom-width: 0; height: 100%; bottom: 0; top:0; overflow:auto;"><?php include '../module/job.unclicked.php' ?></div>
            <div id="details" style="width:100%; border-left-width: thin; border-right-width: 0; border-top-width: thin; border-bottom-width: 0; height: 100%; bottom: 0; top:0; overflow:auto;">
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td width="150px" style="padding:0; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); vertical-align:top;">
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**Job.call.php file**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job  where approved='1' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

echo "<table id='maintable' class='table-fill' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:400px;'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    if (strlen($row['positiontitle']) > 23) $row['positiontitle'] = substr($row['positiontitle'], 0, 22) . "...";
        if (strlen($row['companyname']) > 23) $row['companyname'] = substr($row['companyname'], 0, 35) . "...";
        if (strlen($row['location']) > 23) $row['location'] = substr($row['location'], 0, 13) . "...";
        if (strlen($row['jobcategory']) > 19) $row['jobcategory'] = substr($row['jobcategory'], 0, 18) . "...";

echo "<tr onclick=\"get_data(123)\" ref=\"job.details.php?id=".$row['id']."\" target=\"content\" class=\"positiontitle-link\" data-id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">";
  echo "<td position='fixed' overflow='hidden' width='11%'><font style='text-shadow: none;'>" . $row['positiontitle']  ."</font> <br> <font style='font-size:10px;'>". $row['companyname']."</font></a></td>";
  echo "<td position='fixed' width='7%'>" . $row['location'] . " <br> <font style='font-size:10px;'>". $row['jobcategory']."</font></td>";
  echo "<td style='padding:0;' width='5%'>" . $row['closingdate'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>"; 
    }

echo "</table>"
```

**My Question:**

When i click on a job in first column the job loads correctly but when i click on back button of the browser to go to the previous page the url change but the page is not loading.

**I think there is a problem in this code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.hash) {
       var id = window.location.hash.replace('#id-', '');
       $('#details').load('job.details.php?id=' + id);

       //-----job.unclick.hide.row.select
      var div = document.getElementById("job.unclicked");
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Ajax, the browser do not save the history of loading page. So you need to add the page history explicitly in browsers cache. Some plugins might help you http://www.sitepoint.com/history-back-button-plugins/

Comment: Thanks, but all the sources are for static pages, i use to call data from mysql database.

Comment: On Browsers back button previous page will be called not the same page loaded by AJAX so you need to push that url explicitly in Browser's cache so on click of back button that URL will be called not the one which is calling previous page

Comment: Thanks, can you help me how to embed it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Browser history won't get updated during AJAX calls.

Following are the possible solutions,

1. HTML5 has introduced history.pushState() & history.popState() - **[Check here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method)**
2. Jquery plugins could be used - **[Check here...](http://www.sitepoint.com/history-back-button-plugins/)**
3. Manually saving the state of every page/ajax calls in Javascript and using the same on page
   load, which needs more effort for accomplishing